# DuplicateRuleHeader includeRecordDetails not recognized

Tags: duplicate-management

All my environments have been upgraded to the API Version 34.0 that was released on the Summer of 2015. I have created duplicated management rules, which I am trying to invoke via code behind of a custom visual force page. But I am getting this error

> Variable does not exist: includeRecordDetails

Somehow the other property that was release `runAsCurrentUser` seems to be recognized. I have also attached a screenshot. Any help would be appreciated

```
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions(); 
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.includeRecordDetails = true; //--VED: Not Working with API 34.0
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = false;
dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.runAsCurrentUser = true;
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(busAddressobj, dml);
```

[image]

Comment: Was a solution ever provided to this?
I am getting the same "Variable does not exist" error.
The version of my ApexClass is set to 35.0. Any help would be appreciated. Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation for the "DMLOptions.DuplicateRuleHeader" class does not list these properties.

Only the properties "allowSave" and "runAsCurrentUser" are allowed.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader.htm#apex_class_Database_DMLOptions_DuplicateRuleHeader)